# Run threads sequentially in multiple thread group and thread group in parallel - JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I need to setup an test with respect to following scenario

1. Thread Group 1(Stepping thread group) (HTTP request 1 should continue for 5 min, **THEN** Http request 2 should be picked up for 5 min and finally for http request 3 - i.e 15 min test)

- HTTP Request 1
- HTTP Request 2
- HTTP Request 3

2. Thread Group 2(Stepping thread group) (HTTP request 4 should continue for 5 min, **THEN** Http request 5 should be picked up for 5 min and finally for http request 6 - i.e 15 min test)

- HTTP Request 4
- HTTP Request 5
- HTTP Request 6

3. Thread Group 3(Stepping thread group) (HTTP request 7 should continue for 5 min, **THEN** Http request 8 should be picked up for 5 min and finally stop - i.e 10 min test)

- HTTP Request 7
- HTTP Request 8

**All of the above thread group should run in parallel as a test plan**

How to achieve or setup the above scenario in a testplan

Answer (score 0):

1. For running thread groups in parallel make sure that on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

   [image]
2. For running a Sampler for 5 minutes put it under the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

   [image]

Another option is just moving the requests into separate Thread Groups, if you need to pass any data between them - go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm)